# {% something %} syntax in django tutorial

Tags: python, django

In the Django tutorial (part 3), they have the following syntax for a template:

```
{% if latest_poll_list %}
   <ul>
   {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
   <li><a href="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Can someone explain exactly hwo the {% *something* %} syntax is supposed to work? Thank you for your help!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are template-tags. In the relevant part of the actual Python-code the tutorial does this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

from polls.models import Question

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

This is the view. In this view they populate `latest_question_list` with the five newest questions from the database. Then the view is told to render the output with these values.

The view then loads the template (the code you posted) and replaces the tags/placeholders with actual data from the corresponding object.

The template-tags should be pretty self-explainable. The first line checks if there are any questions provided. If it is, loop them and `{{ poll.id }}` etc will then be replaced by the actual data from the query.

This is more or less the "core" of this type of design. The idea is to separate the logic and the markup as much as possible. You should have all your code in the views and just the plain markup and template-tags in the template-files. It provides a much cleaner environment and makes it much easier to maintain.

Comment: Hm, the code seems to make sense, I agree, and I get the syntax. But is {% %} part of python or part of Django?

Comment: @user1357015 - It's a part of Django's template-engine. They have just decided how Django expects the template to be formatted and does some cleaver replace/parsing before returning the content to the user.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. So what this is really saving is typing much longer python code that checks if there are any input variables, etc etc. This just auto-magically, just handles all of that? It seems that in pure Python, if everything was in just one file, I could get rid of {% %}. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1357015 - Like I wrote in the last paragraph, this is the model/template/view-approach which Django follows. If you don't like it yet, fear not. Sooner or later you will love the fact the the source is divided up like this. It makes things a LOT easier. Btw, here's the parser for the `If`-tag if you're interested: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/smartif.py

Comment: Don't forget that Django has its own webserver and Apache module plugin. If you're familiar with php, the `{% something %}` is a concentrated way of the '<?php ?>` tags within the .php file.  Django processes the template tags and inserts the relevant HTML structures with the values contained inside the variables passed to it.